# C Access 2D char array via Pointer

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

I am trying to access a 2D array of chars. I have a pointer on right address but somehow dreferencing is not working.

```
    char ary[5][8];
char temp[8];
int i;

char **a_ptr = &ary;

    for(i=0; i<5; i++){
        sprintf(temp, "0x10%d" , i);
        strcpy(ary[i] , temp);
        printf("~~~%s@0x%x == 0x%x" , ary[i] , &ary[i] , (a_ptr + i));

    }

    for(i=0; i<5; i++){//This wont work. 
        printf("~~~%s@0x%x" , *(a_ptr + i) ,  (a_ptr + i));

    }
```

Below is the output of this fucniton before it breaks to derefence the pointer.

Output Format : Value@Address

```
0x100@0x5fbff408 == 0x5fbff408
0x101@0x5fbff410 == 0x5fbff410
0x102@0x5fbff418 == 0x5fbff418
0x103@0x5fbff420 == 0x5fbff420
0x104@0x5fbff428 == 0x5fbff428
```

As we can see in above output that array values are filled correctly and a_ptr is pointing to correct addresses (&ary[i] == (a_ptr + i)).

But when the pointer is deference then it breaks there. Even using the [] operators does the same.

```
*(a_ptr + i); //Breaks
a_ptr[i]; //Breaks as well
```

However, (a_ptr + i) points to the right address.

Thanks,

Answer (score 6):

`char **a_ptr = &ary;` - this makes no sense. `char** a_ptr` is a pointer to a pointer. What you need is a pointer to an array. The following will do:

```
char (*a_ptr)[8] = ary; // also don't take the address of the array
```

If you're trying to print the pointer address, `printf` has a format for this `%p`. Replace your `0x%x`s with `%p`.

I've edited your code as follows and my compiler no longer issues warnings:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char ary[5][8];
    char temp[8];
    int i;

    char (*a_ptr)[8] = ary;

    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        sprintf(temp, "0x10%d" , i);
        strcpy(ary[i] , temp);
        printf("~~~%s@%p == %p" , ary[i] , &ary[i] , (a_ptr + i));

    }

    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        printf("~~~%s@%p" , *(a_ptr + i) ,  (a_ptr + i));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And now my output is:

```
$ ./a.out 
~~~0x100@0xbfc77a74 == 0xbfc77a74~~~0x101@0xbfc77a7c == 0xbfc77a7c~~~0x102@0xbfc77a84 == 0xbfc77a84~~~0x103@0xbfc77a8c == 0xbfc77a8c~~~0x104@0xbfc77a94 == 0xbfc77a94~~~0x100@0xbfc77a74~~~0x101@0xbfc77a7c~~~0x102@0xbfc77a84~~~0x103@0xbfc77a8c~~~0x104@0xbfc77a94
```

Is this what you were hoping to get?

Some code that relies only on pointers and no arrays:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> /* for strcpy */
#include <stdlib.h> /* for free and malloc */

int main()
{

    char** two_d = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 5); /* allocate memory for 5 pointers to pointers */

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) /* for each of the five elements */
    {
        two_d[i] = malloc(2); /* allocate memory to each member of two_d for a 2 char string */

        strcpy(two_d[i], "a"); /* store data in that particular element */

        printf("%s has address of %p\n", two_d[i], &two_d[i]); /* print the contents and the address */

        free(two_d[i]); /* free the memory pointer to by each pointer */
    }

    free(two_d); /* free the memory for the pointer to pointers */

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works great and output is exactly what was expected. But don't want to use pointer to array     (char *a_ptr[8]) and want to stick with pointer to pointer as it is same.  

Ok the problem is with dereferencing.  
  
 printf("~~~%s@%p" , (a_ptr + i) ,  (a_ptr + i));  

If deference without '*' operator than the values can be accessed. Frankly, I have no idea why is that. Shouldn't     *(a_ptr + i) syntax working? Or a_ptr[i] should work as well.

Comment: `char ary[5][8]` only allocates memory for 40 characters, and no pointers. If you want pointers to pointers, then declare `char *ary[5]`, and then initialize each of those five pointers with a different pointer to 8 chars. Pointers are not arrays.

Comment: Then howcome below can work.  
 char **a_ptr = &ary; 
 printf("~~~%s@%p" , (a_ptr + i) , (a_ptr + i));  
  
This will show the values correctly. but still, dereferencing wont work!

Comment: I'm honestly not convinced it works, the compiler emits a warning:
' warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]'. When I run your original code (with the fix for printing pointer addresses) I get a segmentation fault. This is with GCC on Linux.

Comment: @Nobilis perhaps you are correct. Interestingly, it works with i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 complier. At-least I can see the correct output. But it certainly breaks here http://codepad.org/6hamacpH Any idea whats happening?

Comment: @user2492889 If you insist on using just pointers to pointers then I've added a small snippet of code that uses dynamic memory to manage pointers to pointers. I've annotated it with comments, ask me if something is unclear. You should be able to easily compile it and I can guarantee there are no memory leaks.

Comment: @Nobilis Yeah, thats the way it should be, however, bit different then OP. Checkout how it works here http://codepad.org/Bt6d3sd3  I have used hard coded (k+=2) increment value to move the pointer. The idea is first one should check the address width of array elements and increment the pointer accordingly. And yes, I still dont understand why deference operators * and [] does not work in this example.

Comment: @user2492889 there are problems with your code, my compiler says the following: `10:17: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]`, `21:4: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char **’ [-Wformat]`. I'm assuming GCC is trying to make it work as much as possible. Try addressing these and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: @user2492889: You wrote that you want to stick with pointer to pointer “as it is same”. It is **not** the same. A pointer to an array is a pointer to the data. It is the same address as the first element of the array. So it has the same value as a pointer to the data; only the type is different: The compiler knows there are multiple values at the pointed-to location. A pointer to pointer is a pointer to a pointer to data. It has a different value than a pointer to an array. They cannot be used in the same ways.